# `kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat` in AVCaptureVideoDataOutput doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

According to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelFormatDescriptionRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Pixel_Format_Types), `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` should allow images to be captured as float32 RGBA (128 bits total) via the pixel format option: `kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat`.

The documentation states this works from iOS 6 onwards, but it doesn't appear to work in iOS 9.

```
let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
var settings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString:kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat]
output.videoSettings = settings
output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
```

returns

```
RGfA (1380410945) is not a supported pixel format type.  See AVCaptureOutput.h for a list of supported formats.  Available pixel format types on this platform are (
    420v,
    420f,
    BGRA
).'
```

[This site](http://blog.christopherhelf.at/?p=118) discusses a workaround, but I can't get this code to work properly in swift 2.0. I have a separate post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749638/get-ios-camera-to-output-floating-point-values-in-swift-2) trying to correct this code.

Has anyone managed to make `kCVPixelFormatType_128RGBAFloat` work in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a future format and currently is not supported.
Alternatively, even if it is, in the case of camera, it would most likely be a RGBA 8888 representation that is scaled to fit into [0..1] range.

At least current camera sensor types (according to spec sheet) do not support more than 8 bit per channel as output data.